# Remove spacing in matlab subplot in odd/even vector

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Im new in Matlab. I tried to subplot multiple images using previous example on this problem and it works. However,  it shows 5x5 array insted of 5x6 array. What if the number of images(case of study im on right now) are odd? How to plot images based on odd number of array? Here is my code. Please help me.Any help is greatly appreciated

```
1. figure;
2. for n=1:30
3.    filename= fullfile(input_dir,filenames(n).name);
4.    img = imread(filename);
5.    img1 = imcrop(img,[79 90 95 127]);
6.    img2=histeq(img1);
7. 
8. I = img2;
9. A = imnoise(I,'salt & pepper',0.01);
10. A=double(A);

11. [ imf_matrix ] = bemd( A );
12. imf1 = imf_matrix(:,:,1);


13.a = mat2gray(imf1);
14.subplot('Position',[(mod(n-1,5))/5 1-(ceil(n/5))/5 1/5 1/5]),imshow(a);
15.
16. 
17.
18. anger(:,n) = imf1(:);
19. 
20. 
21.
22.end
23.p = get(gcf,'Position');
24.k = [size(a,2) size(a,1)]/(size(a,2)+size(a,1));
25.set(gcf,'Position',[p(1) p(2) (p(3)+p(4)).*k])
26.
27.an=anger';
```

Here is my result[salt and pepper at 10% noise density](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4NsI.png)

Comment: One of your arguments to `subplot` is not calculated right. `subplot(m,n,p) `divides the current figure into an `m`-by-`n` grid and creates axes in the position specified by `p`.

Comment: Thankyou Svaberg for responding but im using this subplot('Position',positionVector).I think the problems origin are from positionVector. How to define it? Can you help me sir

Comment: Using normal subplot(m,n,p) will clearly give the answer but i want to get rid of white space consuming my figure so I find an answer related to post "removing spacing in matlab subplot".But the problems is i have many arrays and they consist of even and odd number of vector

Answer (score 1):

you had a problem with your `bottom` part of the `'Position'`:

```
for ii = 1:30
    im = im2double(imread('cameraman.tif'));
    im = imresize(im,[40 30]);
    a = imrotate(im,randi(360),'bilinear','crop');
    left = (mod(ii-1,5))/5;
    bottom = (floor((ii-1)/5))/6;
    % or: bottom = 5/6 - (floor((ii-1)/5))/6;
    subplot('Position',[left, bottom, 1/5, 1/6]);
end
```

[image]

however, you can also do it like that:

```
for ii = 1:30
    im = im2double(imread('cameraman.tif'));
    im = imresize(im,[40 30]);
    a = imrotate(im,randi(360),'bilinear','crop');
    if ii == 1
        A = zeros(size(a,1)*6,size(a,2)*5);
    end
    row = floor((ii - 1)/5);
    col = mod(ii - 1,5);
    A((1:40) + row*40,(1:30) + col*30) = a;
end
figure;
imshow(A)
```

Comment: Thankyou sir. I will try it ASAP

Comment: Hello sir! Thanks for the code.It work like a charm. However I have another problems with white space consuming my figure. Based on the answer you give me could you include how to remove any of white space. Thank you in advance

Comment: Try the second code (to plot them all in the same **image**), it will give you an image with no spaces.

Comment: Will do sir.Tq :)

Comment: Thank you very much sir. The code are running like I want :)))

Comment: Sorry to bother you again @user2999345 can i ask how to deal with odd number of ii. For example ii=17,31 ,32...